# VSCodeから実行すると正常に動くが、exeファイルから実行するとエラーになる

Tags: python, vscode

タイトルにも書きましたが、VSCodeから実行すると正常に動くけど、exeファイルから実行すると23番目でエラーになります。

取得してくるファイルは１つだけなので、wb = px.load_workbook(SV5[0])であっていると思うのですが、何か間違っているのでしょうか？

[image: コードです、23番でエラーになります]

[image: エラー内容です]

[image: ライン10で取得するファイルは一つだけです]

Comment: `23番目でエラー`とはエラーメッセージの`line 23`のことだと思われますが、それは`23行目でエラー`を指していますので認識を改めてください。それから質問に貼り付けたファイルアイコンの拡張子は`.csv`に見えますが、スクリプトで問題発生直前の21行目で検索しているのは拡張子`.xlsx`のファイルですので、それが合っていないだけでは？ こちらのヘルプ記事などを参考に質問内容をブラッシュアップしてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765)

Comment: 「vscodeから実行すると正常に動くけど、exeファイルから実行するとエラーになる」のであれば、exeファイルの作成方法に問題があるのかもしれません。作成方法について質問に追記されると良いかと思います。

Comment: 他のご質問について、どれも未解決でしょうか。
もし未解決でしたら問題点を追記してください。
既存の回答で解決済みでしたら[回答の承認](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1736)をお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

読み取り対象のcsvファイルを以下のフォルダに配置(コピペ)して、エラーが解消するか試してください。

```
C:\Users\4046879\Desktop\pythonkasika\dist\
```

以下、補足と解説です。
[`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#glob.glob)関数は、`root_dir`引数を指定しなければ**カレントディレクトリから**ファイルを取得します。
VS Codeで実行した時と、生成したexeファイルを実行した時でカレントディレクトリが異なっている可能性があります。
(カレントディレクトリの説明は省きます)

カレントディレクトリは[`os.getcwd`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20getcwd#os.getcwd)で取得可能です。
9行目に下記の2行のコードを追加してください。

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

このコードに出力された文字列がVS Codeとexe実行時で異なり、かつexe実行時の文字列が示すフォルダに対象のcsvファイルが入っていないならばそれがエラーの原因です。